# Protege reasoner highlighting class with red colour

Tags: ontology, protege

I created classes and subclasses in Protege, and when I applied the Reasoner, the color of some classes changed to red.

Anyone have an idea why?

Solve the problem in my ontology in order to ensure it remains consistent.

I tried also to make some properties between classes but it did not work with this highlighting.

Comment: You have unsatisfiable classes or your ontology is inconsistent. We will need to see your ontology to know what is wrong. Please provide a minimal example of your ontology illustrating the problem.